# trying to Run the SSIS package from ADF which are accessing file from Network Path

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, ssis-2012

I m trying to Execute the SSIS package from ADF.
Pacakage are having the Network Path.
I have SHIR insatalled into the server where the Network path file and SSIS pacakges are avaiable i have set the connectByproxy=True  into the SSIS packages File connection Manger Proxy. But When i try to execute the pacakge i m getting below error:

DFT - dbo_history:Error: ConnectByProxy: Staging task failed. TaskStatus: Failed, ErrorCode: 2906, ErrorMessage: Package execution failed. For more details, select the output of your activity run on the same row.,  dbo_history:Error: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80131505 (Timeout when reading from staging). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using

Please help it's critical

Try to Execute the SSIS prackage from ADF

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I may have the same problem. It seems that service (ssis IR) is not finished